# Book on yeast reproduction, evolution and on the use of yeast as model organism

Tags: evolution, reproduction, experimental-design, book-recommendation, yeast

I am looking for a good book in:

- Yeast reproduction

  - mating types
  - Recombination
  - mating type determination mechanism
- Yeast evolution
- Yeast as model organism and its use in experimental biology

  - It should include common technics used to work with yeast. For example: We can add a plasmid in order to fool yeast and let them think they have another mating type than the actually have.

Note: I am mostly interested in [Saccharomyces cerevisiae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae) of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my list, in no particular order.

[Methods in Yeast Genetics](http://www.cshlpress.com/default.tpl?cart=13923940041297048&fromlink=T&linkaction=full&linksortby=oop_title&--eqSKUdatarq=526)

[Some other yeast books at CSHL](http://www.cshlpress.com/default.tpl?cart=13923940041297048&id1=108&startat=1&--woSECTIONSdatarq=108&--SECTIONSword=ww&sortby_1=recency)

Fred Sherman's primer, available free at various sites including [here](http://www.uni-marburg.de/fb20/cyto/lehre/praktikumsunterlagen/vl/hefe/sherman01).

The Freiburg manual [here](http://www.unifr.ch/biochem/assets/files/schneiter/cours/Yeast/YeastGenetics.pdf)

[The timeless classics (link to volume 3 but see all volumes)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0879693649)

The [YeastBook](http://www.genetics.org/site/misc/yeastbook.xhtml) is an attempt to build a current encyclopaedia to replace the previous item on my list.

The [Saccharomyces genome database](http://www.yeastgenome.org), probably the best organism-specific resource ever.